# unix command, remove white spaces in text file with delimeter

Tags: unix

I have text file,

Input file:

```
sno|name|lab|result|dep

1|aaa|ALB|<= 3.67|CHE

2|bbb|WBC|>   7.2|FVC

3|ccc|RBC|> 14|CHE
```

Output file:

```
sno|name|lab|result|dep

1|aaa|ALB|<=3.67|CHE

2|bbb|WBC|>7.2|FVC

3|ccc|RBC|>14|CHE
```

How to remove white spaces in column 4(result)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can remove spaces from everything, just use [`sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

```
sed 's/ //g' input.txt > output.txt
```

Or even [`tr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) (translate):

```
tr -d ' ' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Otherwise, if you need to edit just the fourth column, use [`awk`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk). The following command considers `|` as field separator (`-F \|`) and then outputs files using `|` as output field separator (`-vOFS=\|`).

```
awk -F \| -vOFS=\| '{gsub(/ /, "", $4); print; }' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Executed 3 rd statement for removing whitespaces in column 4th but wherever space is there then delimiter is not displayed

Comment: @vsraju Fixed, the default output field separator is a space. You can control the output field separator using the `OFS` variable.